# Courier can not find mail directory?

Tags: email, freebsd

I use postfix+courier+ldap
now my mail stored in vmail/domains/user/new
but when i telnet localhost 143 i got some error

This is Error from maillog

```
imapd: test2@example.org: chdir() failed!!

imapd: error: No such file or directory

authdaemond: Authenticated: sysusername=<null>, sysuserid=5000, sysgroupid=5000, homedir=, address=test2@example.org, fullname=test2 test2, maildir=<null>, quota=<null>, options=<null>
```

why nothing in chdir?

What i should to do?
Sorry about my english 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The settings for homedir and maildir should not be empty. 
They are configured somewhere in your LDAP configuration

Check this thread with a similar problem 
http://www.mail-archive.com/courier-imap@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01562.html